# Hello. I'd like to play a video on my app on android, I tried with videoplayer, it works but doesn't load the video simply open theUI but not thevideo

Tags: python, ffmpeg, kivy, python-for-android, ffpyplayer

I'd like to play a video on my app on android, I tried with videoplayer, it works but doesn't load the video ( simply open the UI but not the video).

I found out i may need ffpyplayer so I changed buildozer requirements:
requirements = python3,kivy, android,ffpyplayer

but buildozer failed to build apk when i added ffpyplayer and ffmpeg in buildozer.spec file in requirement.

```
[DEBUG]:    If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
[DEBUG]:    version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
[DEBUG]:    ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
[DEBUG]:    Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
[DEBUG]:    solve the problem.
Exception in thread background thread for pid 77802:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-protocol=https,tls_openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libshine --enable-libvpx --enable-parsers --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --disable-symver --disable-programs --disable-doc --enable-filter=aresample,resample,crop,adelay,volume,scale --enable-protocol=file,http,hls,udp,tcp --enable-small --enable-hwaccels --enable-pic --disable-static --disable-debug --enable-shared --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=armv7a-linux-androideabi21- --arch=arm --strip=/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --sysroot=/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --enable-neon --prefix=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg

  STDOUT:
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1297, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 730, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 215, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 505, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/ffmpeg/__init__.py", line 143, in build_arch
    shprint(configure, *flags, _env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-protocol=https,tls_openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libshine --enable-libvpx --enable-parsers --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --disable-symver --disable-programs --disable-doc --enable-filter=aresample,resample,crop,adelay,volume,scale --enable-protocol=file,http,hls,udp,tcp --enable-small --enable-hwaccels --enable-pic --disable-static --disable-debug --enable-shared --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=armv7a-linux-androideabi21- --arch=arm --strip=/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --sysroot=/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --enable-neon --prefix=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg

  STDOUT:
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,ffpyplayer,kivy,openssl,certifi,android,pytube,plyer,pyjnius,kivmob,jnius,future,libshine,libx264,ffpyplayer_codecs,Pillow,liblzma,opencv,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,youtube_search --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.4.1.1043-1'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-2'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = '875ade0bb031'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.3.2.152-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-2=11.2.152-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.4.1.1152-1'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '60'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.4.1.1152-1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20221021'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.8.4-1+cuda11.2'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.2.2-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-2=11.3.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.4.1.1043-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-2=11.4.1.1043-1'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.1.1.33'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.254'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.2.2'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-2'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-2'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.2 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.3.2.152-1'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.2.152-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '30'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

kindly help me anyone would be very appreciate thank you.

Comment: You need to post your code. If this isn't code you've written, then you should report the problem to the programmer, not post here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to run it on android, you also need to add ffpyplayer_codecs to the requirements in the spec file and modify the p4a.branch from master to develop and it should work. Don't forget to delete the .buildozer directory before you recompile the apk.

Comment: Hi Norbert Tiborcz,  thanks for replying i added ffpyplayer_codecs in requirement it get compiled but not playing video with ffpyplayer_codecs need to compile ffmpeg and ffpyplayer but whenever i adding ffmpeg and ffpyplayer in requirement buildozer failed to build apk it's showing some error above i  posted that errors.

Comment: Hello community, thanks for the reply, my problem is i whenever I adding ffmpeg and ffpyplayer in buildozer.spec file in requirement, buildozer failed to build apk what is the reason to failed buildozer , i posted error above.   And here also error that showing If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.